# Checkboxes with parent and child selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a row of checkboxes and I want the following:
- when clicking the parent select/unselect all child checkboxes
- when all checkboxes are checked (including the parent) and you uncheck one of the child checkboxes, the parent should also uncheck.

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //clicking the parent checkbox should check or uncheck all child checkboxes
    $(".parentCheckBox").click(
        function() {
            $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.childCheckBox').attr('checked', this.checked);
        }
    );
    //clicking the last unchecked or checked checkbox should check or uncheck the parent checkbox
    $('.childCheckBox').click(
        function() {
            if ($(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false)
            $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked', false);
            if (this.checked == true) {
                var flag = true;
                $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.childCheckBox').each(
                    function() {
                        if (this.checked == false)
                        flag = false;
                    }
                );
                $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked', flag);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

And here it is in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2b2hw58d/1/

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: use `.prop('checked', this.checked)`

Comment: also `.closest('fieldset')` instead of `.parents('fieldset:eq(0)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) also, use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest ancestor element matching the selector.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //clicking the parent checkbox should check or uncheck all child checkboxes
    $(".parentCheckBox").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.childCheckBox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    //clicking the last unchecked or checked checkbox should check or uncheck the parent checkbox
    $('.childCheckBox').click(function () {
        var $fs = $(this).closest('fieldset');
        $fs.find('.parentCheckBox').prop('checked', !$fs.find('.childCheckBox').is(':not(:checked)'))
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x511yemq/)

Answer (score 1):

In this `parents('fieldset:eq(0)')` part `:eq(0)` isn't needed and use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b2hw58d/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //clicking the parent checkbox should check or uncheck all child checkboxes
    $(".parentCheckBox").click(
        function() {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.childCheckBox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        }
    );
    //clicking the last unchecked or checked checkbox should check or uncheck the parent checkbox
    $('.childCheckBox').click(
        function() {
            if ($(this).closest('fieldset').find('.parentCheckBox').prop('checked') == true && this.checked == false)
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.parentCheckBox').prop('checked', false);
            if (this.checked == true) {
                var flag = true;
                $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.childCheckBox').each(
                    function() {
                        if (this.checked == false)
                        flag = false;
                    }
                );
                $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.parentCheckBox').prop('checked', flag);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Use 'prop' instead of 'attr'.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/m3o7u7Lm/1/